# finding a comma in string

Tags: matlab, indexing

`[23567,0,0,0,0,0]` and other value is `[452221,0,0,0,0,0]` and the value should be contineously displaying about 100 values and then i want to display only the sensor value like in first sample `23567` and in second sample `452221` , only the these values have to display . For that I have written a code
`value = str2double(str(2:7));`[see here my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4mL1.png)
so **I want to find the comma in the output and only display the value before first comma**

Comment: See [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html), [`sscanf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html), [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), etc...

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in a comment by excaza, MATLAB has dedicated functions, such as [`sscanf`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html) for such purposes.

```
sscanf(str,'[%d')
```

which matches but ignores the first `[`, and returns the next (i.e. the first) number as a double variable, and not as a string.

Still, I like the idea of using regular expressions to match the numbers. Instead of matching all zeros and commas, and replacing them by `''` as proposed by Sardar_Usama, I would suggest directly matching the numbers using [`regexp`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html).

You can return all numbers  in `str` (still as string!) with

```
nums = regexp(str,'\d*','match')
```

and convert the first number to a double variable with

```
str2double(nums{1})
```

To match only the first number in `str`, we can use the regexp

```
nums = regexp(str,'[(\d*),','tokens')
```

which finds a `[`, then takes an arbitrary number of decimals (0-9), and stops when it finds a `,`. By enclosing the `\d*` in brackets, only the parts in brackets are returned, i.e. only the numbers without `[` and `,`.

**Final Note:** if you continue working with strings, you could/should consider the `regexp` solution. If you convert it to a double anyways, using `sscanf` is probably faster and easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`regexprep`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) as follows:

```
str='[23567,0,0,0,0,0]' ;
required=regexprep(str(2:end-1),',0','')
%Taking str(2:end-1) to exclude brackets, and then removing all ,0
```

If there can be values other than `0` after `,` , you can use the following more general approach instead:

```
required=regexprep(str(2:end-1),',[-+]?\d*\.?\d*','')
```